# ImageIcon squished flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I am building a flutter web app, and I need to make something that looks like this: [image], so for this I use a row. This is how I am making this:

```
            Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Container(
              height: height / 25,
              width: width / 18,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border:
                      Border.all(width: 2, color: CustomColours.lightBlue),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Text('1000   '),
                  ImageIcon(
                    AssetImage(
                      'lib/assets/fonts/icons/Group 1.png',
                    ),
                    color: Colors.white,
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              height: height / 25,
              child: FittedBox(
                fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                child: IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.add_circle_outline,
                      color: CustomColours.lightBlue,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      print('add');
                    }),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

However, this turns out like this, with the Icon not working correctly:[image]
This is the icon I use: [image] (it is 50*50 pixels).

What can I do to fix this? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can warp the custom icon to the `FittedBox` widget and set its dimensions to the `Container` and wrap it to the `FittedBox` parent to achieve this scenario. Because FittedBox takes the `constraints` from its parent widget. I don't have your custom icon. So, I have used the framework icon to represent it.

```
return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Container(
          height: 50,
          width: 100,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(width: 2, color: Colors.lightBlue),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text(
                '1000  ',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
              ),
              Container(
                width: 30,
                height: 30,
                child: FittedBox(
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.adjust_sharp,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        FittedBox(
          fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
          child: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.add_circle_outline,
                color: Colors.lightBlue,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                print('add');
              }),
        ),
      ],
    );
```

[image]